# laravel 5.2 project not working on webserver

Tags: php, laravel, webserver, laravel-5, internal-server-error

this is my **web server** directory

[image]

**Data** folder contains all project code
and **public folder** data resides in **public_html/alpha**

like this

[image]

my **index.php** file which is in **public_html/aplha**

```
require __DIR__.'/../../data/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../data/bootstrap/app.php';
```

and finally my **server.php** file

```
require_once __DIR__.'../public_html/alpha/index.php';
```

i have also given all **permissions** to public files but still getting **Inter Server Error**

i am trying to make **domain.com/alpha home directory**
and **route '/'** will be called like **domain.com/alpha/**

Comment: Check your webserver logs.

Comment: i have checked but nothing useful

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a Laravel project inside your /alpha

Comment: its in root directory in folder name "data" @Victor Souto

Answer (score 0):

Their are some simple steps for run projetc on server..

1. First Project will upload in /public_html or (/public_html/Project_name)
2. Check Your php version.. Because its only compatible with php 5 or above
3. Rewrite module must be enabled on server.
4. Rmaining part must be same as like your local project then run it on the domain.

Comment: its not recommended to upload all project data to public_html folder, so i have uploaded the project data in root directory. and current php version is 5.6.

Comment: Yes , I appreciate with you. But generally these steps are  working fine for each and every Project.